How can I use custom variables in Loguru in Python?
I don't want the structure the Loguru gives me. I want to use a custom serialized json base structure.
for eg:
 {
   "time": "5:30pm",
   "error": "Type error,
 }

I don't want any extra params.
From the source code I think it comes from this function:
 @staticmethod
def _serialize_record(text, record):
    exception = record["exception"]

    if exception is not None:
        exception = {
            "type": None if exception.type is None else exception.type.__name__,
            "value": exception.value,
            "traceback": bool(exception.traceback),
        }

    serializable = {
        "text": text,
        "record": {
            "elapsed": {
                "repr": record["elapsed"],
                "seconds": record["elapsed"].total_seconds(),
            },
            "exception": exception,
            "extra": record["extra"],
            "file": {"name": record["file"].name, "path": record["file"].path},
            "function": record["function"],
            "level": {
                "icon": record["level"].icon,
                "name": record["level"].name,
                "no": record["level"].no,
            },
            "line": record["line"],
            "message": record["message"],
            "module": record["module"],
            "name": record["name"],
            "process": {"id": record["process"].id, "name": record["process"].name},
            "thread": {"id": record["thread"].id, "name": record["thread"].name},
            "time": {"repr": record["time"], "timestamp": record["time"].timestamp()},
        },
    }

    return json.dumps(serializable, default=str, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n"

From handler.
I tried overriding it, but was unable to do it.
Can anyone give me a better solution to achieve this?
I am using it in FastAPI.

Is your goal to add the log to a file or for the JSON log to be directly consumed by FastAPI?

Can you please tell us exactly how are you unable to override it? Please provide an error message (if there are any) along with text description.

My goal is to add it to a file. and then using filebeat forward it to my logstash server.
I am getting a lot of garbage log i dont want

Please have a look at this answer

I think you are trying to change your log output format
So:
A Complete Guide to Logging in Python with Loguru
Read Customizing Loguru section in this article
Or if you interest to red official documents:
loguru/API Reference/loguru.logger
I think you are looking for
from loguru import logger
logger.format()

You can create a custom fstring f('string{var}') for your logs format and change your output

Remove the default logger and add your custom logging template
# Loguru logic
logger.remove()  # Remove the default logger
logger.add("YOUR LOG PATH", serialize=False, format=_serialize_record)

Usage:
# Example log entries
logger.error("This is a type error")
logger.warning("This is a warning")

Output Sample:
{
  "time": "05:30 PM",
  "error": "This is a type error",
  "exception_type": null,
  "file": {
    "name": "my_script.py",
    "path": "/path/to/my_script.py"
  },
  "function": "my_function",
  "line": 42,
  "level": "ERROR"
  //will more fields as per your custom temaplte
}

Ref - Adding contextual data to your logs
